# Trouble with jquery ajax and safari when passing a username/password

Tags: jquery, safari

We are trying to pass credentials to our site via jquery ajax (not using php [yeah I know this is unsafe]).

It seems Safari is having trouble with the `username`/`password` attributes of the ajax method. (**[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)**) We are using `jquery 1.5.1`.

Here is example code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some/url",
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    data: 'get=login',
    timeout: 7000,
    username: "user",
    password: "pass",
    success: function (data, textStatus, response) {
        Log("success");
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus, response) {
        Log("fail");
    }
});
```

This works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and IE7/8, but Safari won't even send the ajax to the server (did a trace with wireshark and nothing is going down the pipe). Strangely enough, the `error` function gets called.

If I comment out username and password, the ajax is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by using `beforeSend` and creating a request header. Apparently if this isn't included, Safari chokes and doesn't send anything. Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some/url",
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    data: 'get=login',
    timeout: 7000,
    username: "user",
    password: "pass",
    beforeSend: function (req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + btoa("user:password"));
    }
    success: function (data, textStatus, response) {
        Log("success");
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus, response) {
        Log("fail");
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work: you are missing to encode the credentials as well as the 'Basic' tag.
`req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));`

Answer (score 2):

Is more simple:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some/url",
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    data: 'get=login',
    timeout: 7000,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Base64.encode("username:password")
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, response) {
        Log("success");
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus, response) {
        Log("fail");
    }
});
```

This works for me.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the anti-phising warning that Safari displays when you click on a URL containing a username and password?

> http://username:password@example.com/

[image: Safari ant-phising warning]

It's likely that it's the same thing that's preventing your AJAX request from even being sent (as it won't actually load the site, and hence send the request, until you click the Ignore button).

Try loading the AJAX request in the main browser, click "Ignore Warning" and then try the AJAX request again to see if it fires.

Comment: No this doesn't happen. In fact, Firefox displays a similar message when I visit the site and firefox/chrome (which is also webkit)/ie all work with the ajax login process I've created

Comment: How different is your example code from what's actually happening? I made a basic-auth protected .json file and using jquery 1.5.1 could successfully retrieve the content in Safari (v5.0.3) using the code above. You're retrieving plain JSON, using the same domain, and not doing any cross-domain JSONP?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that putting "@" in the username or password results in the same behavior you're experience. Safari seems to be picky about what characters you can use...